# How to choose tables on select from all_tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table name template, there are a couple with the same name and a number at the end: fmj.backup_semaforo_geo_THENUMBER, for example:

```
select * from fmj.backup_semaforo_geo_06391442
select * from fmj.backup_semaforo_geo_06398164
...
```

Lets say I need to select a column from every table which succeeds with the 'fmj.backup_semaforo_geo_%' filter, I tried this:

```
    SELECT calle --This column is from the backup_semaforo_geo_# tables
     FROM (SELECT table_name
      FROM all_tables
     WHERE owner = 'FMJ' AND table_name LIKE 'BACKUP_SEMAFORO_GEO_%');
```

But I'm getting the all_tables tables name data:

```
TABLE_NAME
----------
BACKUP_SEMAFORO_GEO_06391442
BACKUP_SEMAFORO_GEO_06398164
...
```

How can I achieve that without getting the all_tables output?

Thanks.

Comment: That's right you've got all tables that belong to FMj user. what result are you expectting to see?

Comment: Now I now it's right, but I need the:

    SELECT table_name
      FROM all_tables
     WHERE owner = 'FMJ' AND table_name LIKE 'BACKUP_SEMAFORO_GEO_%'

to output the series of tables that match that query so I can append that to the outer query so in the end I get something like:

SELECT calle --This column is from the backup_semaforo_geo_# tables
     FROM BACKUP_SEMAFORO_GEO_06391442, BACKUP_SEMAFORO_GEO_06398164...


I read it now and see I thought it the wrong way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your current query is getting `ORA-00904: "CALLE": invalid identifier`, because the subquery doesn't have a column called `CALLE`. You can't provide a table name to a query at runtime like that, unfortunately, and have to resort to [dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10472/dynamic.htm).

Something like this will loop through all the tables and for each one will get all the values of `CALLE` from each one, which you can then loop through. I've used `DBMS_OUTPUT` to display them, assuming you're doing this in SQL*Plus or something that can deal with that; but you may want to do something else with them.

```
set serveroutput on

declare
    -- declare a local collection type we can use for bulk collect; use any table
    -- that has the column, or if there isn't a stable one use the actual data
    -- type, varchar2(30) or whatever is appropriate
    type t_values is table of table.calle%type;
    -- declare an instance of that type
    l_values t_values;
    -- declare a cursor to generate the dynamic SQL; where this is done is a
    -- matter of taste (can use 'open x for select ...', then fetch, etc.)
    -- If you run the query on its own you'll see the individual selects from
    -- all the tables
    cursor c1 is
        select table_name,
            'select calle from ' || owner ||'.'|| table_name as query
        from all_tables
        where owner = 'FMJ'
        and table_name like 'BACKUP_SEMAFORO_GEO%'
        order by table_name;
begin
    -- loop around all the dynamic queries from the cursor
    for r1 in c1 loop
        -- for each one, execute it as dynamic SQL, with a bulk collect into
        -- the collection type created above
        execute immediate r1.query bulk collect into l_values;
        -- loop around all the elements in the collection, and print each one
        for i in 1..l_values.count loop
            dbms_output.put_line(r1.table_name ||': ' || l_values(i));
        end loop;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

May be a dynamic SQL in a PLSQL program;

```
for a in (SELECT table_name
            FROM all_tables
            WHERE owner = 'FMJ' AND table_name LIKE 'BACKUP_SEMAFORO_GEO_%')
LOOP
   sql_stmt := ' SELECT calle FROM' || a.table_name;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
   ...
   ...
END LOOP;
```