# Search command to search for Column/field in SQLPLUS for Oracle 10.2

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to search for column/field called `ACC`

I have 28 users. I got that information by this command; to list all schemas:

```
SELECT username FROM all_users ORDER BY username;
```

I am connected to user # 13 in the list called 'ABCD', by this command: `SHOW USER;`

Here is a detailed structure.

```
user1 > Has many tables > each table has many column/field.
user2 > Has many tables > each table has many column/field.
user3 > Has many tables > each table has many column/field.
```

and so on.

I need to search for field or column which is called `ACC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [ALL_TAB_COLUMNS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/statviews_2103.htm#REFRN20277) or DBA_TAB_COLUMNS, depending on your access rights.

The following will get you every table, which has the column `acc` in it and the user who "owns" that table.

```
select owner, table_name
  from dba_tab_columns
 where column_name = 'ACC'
```

ALL_TAB_COLUMNS will display all the tables (and their columns) that are accessible to the user you are logged in as.  DBA_TAB_COLUMNS displays them for everything in the database.

Comment: Thanks but dba_tab_columns or all_tab_columns don't work, it works with USER_TAB_COLUMNS .

Answer (score 1):

If I create a dummy table so I know I have some matching data:

```
create table t42 (field_acct_1 number, field_acct_2 number);
insert into t42 values (123, 456);
insert into t42 values (234, 567);
insert into t42 values (678, 123);
insert into t42 values (123, 123);
```

I can a cursor and bulk collect (to allow for duplicate values) to look for matches, based on the [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12373271/266304) mentioned in comments:

```
set serveroutput on

declare
    type t_values is table of number;
    l_values t_values;

    cursor c1(cp_value number) is
        select owner, table_name, column_name,
            'select "' || column_name
                || '" from "' || owner ||'"."'|| table_name
                || '" where "' || column_name || '" = ' || cp_value
                as query
        from all_tab_columns
        where column_name like '%ACC%'
        and owner != 'SYS'
        and data_type = 'NUMBER'
        order by owner, table_name, column_name;
begin
    for r1 in c1(123) loop
        execute immediate r1.query bulk collect into l_values;
        for i in 1..l_values.count loop
            dbms_output.put_line(r1.owner
               ||'.'|| r1.table_name
               ||'.'|| r1.column_name
               ||':'|| l_values(i));
        end loop;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

I've restricted it to look for `NUMBER` columns to save time, and excluded `SYS` tables, but you can problem add filters to reduce the work it has to do even more. Other than that it's pretty much the same idea; see the embedded comments in the earlier answer to see what's happening if it isn't clear.

And that gives me (as owner.table.column:value):

```
SCOTT.T42.FIELD_ACCT_1:123
SCOTT.T42.FIELD_ACCT_1:123
SCOTT.T42.FIELD_ACCT_2:123
SCOTT.T42.FIELD_ACCT_2:123
```

Comment: do I just paste this in sql plus ? or there is a special way to run this script ?

Comment: I just ran it in SQL*Plus, yes

Comment: All it says is `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.`

Comment: Did you include the `set serveroutput on` command? If so then there may just not be any matching data?

Comment: @mogli - yes, the value you're searching for is the parameter to the `c1()` call. Sorry, should have mentioned that. It can be any number. If it isn't really a number you're looking for then the cursor will need to be tweaked.

Comment: I am searching for 6 digit number and searching for it under any table which starts with '%EVENT%'. I am not getting output, can I change to search in anytype of data base? instead of numbers?

Comment: If the column datatype is not a number then you will need to change it yes; might it be a varchar2 field? Or do you know it is?

Comment: that column is type NUMBER(38).

Comment: This is what i am searching for 
`for r1 in c1(644443) loop`

Comment: @mogli - Assuming you changed the `%ACC%` in my answer to `%EVENT%`, and you're looking for the entire number being `644443` not a part of it (so no 164431 for example), then as far as I can see this ought to report a match. You could add `dbms_output.put_line(r1.query)` in the loop to see what it's looking for. If you're sure the data does exist somewhere, and you know which table it should be in, you could isolate the query and run it manually to check what it finds.

Comment: I am aware of that, I can also change `%ACC%` to `%` to search all ? I am searching for the exact number 644443. all the outputs are 6 digit.  I also added `dbms_output.put_line(r1.query)`, will output show right after query? or do I need to look somewhere else for output? all I am getting is  `26  / PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.`

Comment: @mogli - Run the query from the cursor on its own to check it's finding matches, maybe. If you're seeing no output then either there are no matches, or you didn't turn server output on; can't think of a third explanation...

Comment: can you please explain me what is meaning of ` ||'.'|| ` I have another problem I am working on, it is funtion, I am trying to edit. it has ` ||CLF||`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16715/discussion-between-alex-poole-and-mogli)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out myself.

```
SELECT
      COLUMN_NAME 
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%ACC%';
```

I can also find out the table name by selecting `table_name`

```
SELECT
       COLUMN_NAME,
       TABLE_NAME 
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%ACC%';
```

Following Query is selected from different table, it has more result and shows `OWNER` also.

```
SELECT 
      distinct owner,
      COLUMN_NAME,
      TABLE_NAME 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE COLUMN_NAME like '%ACC%'
```

To search for Table

```
SELECT
      COLUMN_NAME,
      TABLE_NAME 
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME like '%X%'
```

Comment: if someone can help, how to select username it is coming from, that would be more accurate result.

Comment: how can I search for account number example account number `123` inside all the columns?

Comment: Does [this recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12373271/266304) point you in the right direction? You can select the account number from each table in the cursor, and check for the required value in the loop, maybe?

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work with Oracel 10.2. unless I am doing it wrong.